# cant get sql table joining to work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that i want to run a query on, what im trying to do is as follows:

```
TABLE1.name , TABLE1.description, TABLE2.category.
```

The link between TABLE2 and TABLE1 is the product_ID and category_ID which both are on TABLE3

So here's the query im trying to run

```
SELECT table1.name AS product_name,
            table1.description AS product_description,
            table2.name AS product_category
            table3.product_id
            FROM table1
            INNER JOIN table1 a ON table3.product_id = table1.product_id
            INNER JOIN  table2 b ON table3.category_id = table2.category_id
            INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id;
```

The structure of the tables is as follows :
Table1(product_id,name,description)
Table2(category_id,name2)
Table3(product_id,category_id)

Comment: Is both Table2 and Table1 has product_id and category_id?

Comment: Could you give us the description of each table ? The `create table` part of you script for example.

Comment: Add your tables here.

Comment: Table1(product_id,name,description) Table2(category_id,name2) Table3(product_id,category_id)

Answer (score 1):

If you use assign alias  (table1 a, table 2 b) to table then use it otherwise don't assign.
You are Joining  two time table 2 but not table 3 and assuming that table2 and table1  are related  by category_id 
and table3 table1 are related  by both product_id and category_id

```
  SELECT 
       table1.name AS product_name
      ,table1.description AS product_description
      ,table2.name AS product_category
      ,table3.product_id
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2  table1.category_id = table2.category_id ;
  INNER JOIN table3  ON table3.product_id = table1.product_id  
          and table3.category_id = table1.category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your condition of ***Table1.category_id = Table2.category_id*** ?

Comment: WHERE cdxc_product_description.product_id = cdxc_category_description.product_id;
yeah forgot that, but the cli tells me its a syntax in the first inner join
what else do you think is the case??